# Live wallpaper has entirely taken over phone

Tags: applications, live-wallpaper

One of my customers says my live wallpaper has completely taken over the screen. They tried restarting the phone, but all they can see is the live wallpaper. No way to unlock the phone.

Are there any steps that can be done to start the phone without the wallpaper started, so they can uninstall it?

It's a Galaxy S6 and I don't think it's rooted.

(I'm in email conversation and will add details as I get them.)

Comment: Thanks! I emailed instructions to my customer. Hopefully this will do the trick.

Comment: I have no new details; customer hasn't written back yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the information available , it is recommended to put [Galaxy S6 in safe mode](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-29226) .

In safe mode installed apps are inactive and the wall paper app can be uninstalled . Restarting the phone gets it out of safe mode

> - Turn the device off
> - Press and hold the <kbd>Power</kbd> key
> - When the Samsung Galaxy S 6 logo appears, release the <kbd>Power</kbd>
>     key, then immediately press and hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> key
> - Hold the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> key until the device finishes restarting.
>     When 'Safe mode' appears in the bottom left, release the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> key
> - Uninstall apps that cause problems.
>     From the Home screen, tap Apps.
>     Tap Settings.
>     Under 'Device,' tap Applications.
>     Tap Application manager.
>     Swipe right to the DOWNLOADED screen.
>     Tap desired app, then tap Uninstall.
>     Tap Uninstall to confirm